# I have a little bit of confusion regarding sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I have a little bit of confusion regarding sequence here:
Find the value of $S_0, S_1, S_2$ and $A_3$ for sequence $\{S_n\}$ where $S_n$ is
$2^n + 1$
I know that the answer is:

$S_0 = 2^0 + 1 = 2$

$S_1 = 2^1 + 1 = 3$

$S_2 = 2^2 + 1 = 5$

But my question is that is it ok to name the term with a different letter ($\mathbf{A_3}$) instead of ($\mathbf{S_3}$)? Which means that:
$\mathbf{A_3} = 2^3 + 1 = \mathbf{9}$.

Thank you.

Comment: Was the question really given to you as "$S_0, S_1, S_2, A_3$"? That just looks like a typo to me; probably $S_3$ was intended. Otherwise $A_3$ hasn't been defined.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply, yeah it might be a typo

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $S_n$ represents a sum up to $n$, so $A_3$ whould be the 3rd term not the sum.
$$A_3=S_3-S_2=2^3+1-(2^2+1)=4$$

Comment: Thank you for ur answer